# Help with my Trigger Logic

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

In the Below code I want to assign Case to WhatId in my Task record when a case with the same contact as Opportunity is created. I am getting a **`System.NullPointerException`** at `tsk.WhatId = cas1.Id` when I am changing my Opportunity Status to Signed.

```
trigger OpportunityTriggers on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    Map<Id,Contact> con = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    Map<Id,Case> casemap = new Map<Id,Case>();

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){

        con.put(opp.Contact__c,null);

    }

    for(Contact cont : [Select Id from Contact where Id =: con.keyset()]){
        con.put(cont.Id,cont);
    }


    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){

    Contact conts = con.get(opp.Contact__c);


    if(opp.StageName == 'Signed'){
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Subject = 'World Class Onboarding';
        c.Description = 'Please complete the following tasks attached to this case to finish Onboarding';
        c.Origin = 'Phone';
        c.Support_Group__c = 'Transitions';
        c.Priority = 'Medium';
        c.Status = 'New';
        c.ContactId = conts.Id;
    //Invoking Assignment Rules
        AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
        AR = [Select Id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true LIMIT 1];
        Database.DMLOptions dmlopts = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmlopts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId  = AR.Id;
        c.setOptions(dmlopts); 
        }
    }

    insert caseList;

    for(Case cas : [Select Id,ContactId,Subject from Case where Subject = 'World Class Onboarding' AND ContactId =: con3.keyset()]){
        casemap.put(cas.Id,cas);
    }

    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){

    if(opp.StageName == 'Signed'){

    Case cas1 = casemap.get(opp.Contact__c);

        Task tsk = new Task();
        tsk.OwnerId = userinfo.getuserid();
        tsk.Subject = 'LOI Signed and Released';
        tsk.Priority = 'Medium';
        tsk.WhatId = cas1.Id;
        tsk.ActivityDate = System.TODAY()+1;
        taskList.add(tsk);

    }}
      insert taskList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming this call returns a record:

```
Case cas1 = casemap.get(opp.Contact__c);
```

But that condition is not guaranteed. You should add a null check.

```
if (cas1 != null)
{
    taskList.add(new Task(
        OwnerId = ...,
        Subject = ...,
        Etc = ...
    ));
}
```

Good catch by Derek. If you want to map by Contact Id, you have to use a grouping algorithm that allows for multiple matches (you could have two separate `Opportunity` records with the same parent value in `Contact__c`):

```
Map<Id, List<Case>> contactToCases = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
for (Case record : [/*case query*/])
{
    if (!contactToCases.containsKey())
        contactToCases.put(record.ContactId, new List<Case>());
    contactToCases.get(record.ContactId).add(record);
}
```

Then you would need to get the `List` and iterate through:

```
for (Opportunity record : trigger.new)
{
    // the below list might still be nillable
    // for instance if you want to ignore null parent
    // if that's the case, add a null check here similar to what's above
    for (Case child : contactToCases.get(record.Contact__c))
    {
        taskList.add(new Task(/*data*/));
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's issue runs a bit deeper than this though. In the provided code, `casemap` is populated with `Case` Ids as the key. `opp.Contact__c` (assuming it is a lookup to a `Contact`) will never exist in a map keyed on `Case` Ids.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. But I would want to make sure that I fetch my record to insert a task. I am not able to understand please correct me if I am worng I am inserting my case before inserting my task, why would i not get any results Case cas1 = casemap.get(opp.Contact__c);

Comment: Derek, that is right it is a lookup to a contact. Would you know what would be the best way I can populate CaseId in my Task WhatId